# Install same .apk file on different Android platforms

Tags: android, apk

Can the same android apk file be installed on different Android platforms - say, one on Intel x86 and another running on ARM? Does the .apk file need to be compiled separately with different configuration settings for different platforms?

Comment: As long as you don't use Native Libraries and stick with java, the answer is yes, you can use the same apk on different platforms. The vm will take care of running your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will build with your existing config and  generate single .apk file and **Multiple Apk Support** feature will handle the rest.

Refer this : **[Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)**